# orchard cms fresh install no pages or links working error: The page cannot be found

Tags: asp.net, windows-xp, installation, orchardcms

Downloaded Orchard CMS zip
Unzipped and placed the contents of the Orchard folder into a folder in my iis root
Created a virtual directory
Set the framework to 4.0
Configured to map everything to aspnet_isapi.dll 
Opened my localhost/orchard
Opened MS-Server and made a black database
installed Orchard 1.4.2 from my localhost\orchard
All looked well tables were made and got a welcome to orchard home page
Clicked on Dashboard and got an error page can not be found!

Has anyone had this problem? any ideas on what went wrong and how can I fix this?

Thanks
Chris

Comment: It can either be that orchard can't connect to db or orchard doesn't have the correct permission to App_Data